# Add a KafkaEx.ConsumerGroup to application's supervision tree

Tags: apache-kafka, elixir, phoenix-framework

Got a problem while try to add `KafkaEx.ConsumerGroup` into application's supervision tree.

> function KafkaEx.ConsumerGroup.start_link/1 is undefined or private

What should I do to make the consumer working on to listen message in kafka_ex?

Answer (score 0):

I found new library that very easy to integrated, kaffe.
https://github.com/spreedly/kaffe

kaffe is Elixir wrapper around Brod, Brod is kafka client for Erlang native.